# Server name dissapears from rdoConnection.Connect string

Tags: oracle, vb6, database-connection

I'm working with an old Visual Basic 6 application that connects to an Oracle11g server using Remote Data Objects (RDO) 2. Here is my code:

```
Dim rdoCon As New rdoConnection

rdoCon.Connect = "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=os11atst.world;"
Debug.Print rdoCon.Connect '1
'Prompt the user to enter credentials and connect to the server:
rdoCon.EstablishConnection rdDriverComplete, False
Debug.Print rdoCon.Connect '2
```

The first `Debug.Print` gives me this (as expected):

```
DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=os11atst.world;
```

However, the second one gives me this:

```
DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=username;PWD=password;
```

The `SERVER` parameter is missing, even though the connection works fine. This is a problem for me, because I need to know what server the connection is to. I can not simply use the information from the first string, because the user is (and should be) able to change the server in the prompt that asks for username and password.

This problem arose from nowhere, possibly in connection to an upgrade from Windows XP to 7. Previously the program did not exhibit this behaviour, or so I am told by older colleagues. Not 100% sure that is correct, though.

How can I prevent the dissaperance of the server name? Can I get the name of the server in any other way than looking at the connection string?

I am not interested in solutions that include upgrading to something newer than RDO. For external reasons I am stuck with it.

Comment: RDO is a blast-from-the-past.  Put it in a variable? `"..SERVER=" & strLastEnteredOrDefaultServerName`

Comment: @Alex K: I know it's old, but the program has to few users for it to be worth a makeover... Theoretically I could put it in a string, but that would require messing around some with the code (to replace the automatic prompt) and I want to touch this old beast as little as possible to prevent any unforseen problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a not so pretty workaround to solve this. I have a table called `SETTINGS` containing columns `NAME` and `VALUE`. For every database I have simply added the setting `servername` together with the appropriate value. All I need to do to find out what server I am connected to is then to query the DB:

```
SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name = 'servername'
```

This is of course quite an ugly hack, so any better solutions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`rdoCon.EstablishConnection` will override whatever you had previously set.

It sounds like the problem is in the DSN that is installed on this new machine. Compare it to the DSN that was installed on the previous machine.  It had a configuration that you are missing on this new machine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I do appreciate it! I am not using a DSN at all when connecting. (I have tried setting `DSN=''` in the connection string, but it still gives me the same behaviour.) An older machine is unfortunately not available for examination.

Comment: If Windows 7 is a 64 bit edition, then you are almost certainly having conflicts with the drivers since your app is only 32 bit and RDO is old tech.  I know you are not using a DSN, but in this case I would suggest trying a fully configured one as this may help you to maintain the correct connection.   Otherwise, you might have to bite the bullet and convert to ADO which will cope on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: You can also try some of the tips in this article in getting VB6 to run smoothly on 64 bit Windows: http://techapple.net/2013/10/installing-and-running-microsoft-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-7windows-8-x64-64-bit-with-all-features/

Comment: My VB6 is indeed installed in the `Program Files (x86)` folder. Interesting. Will try to move it as soon as I get the opportunity and report back. Thank you very much!

Comment: I know it has been some time, but I just wanted to report for future readers that moving Visual Studio from `Program (x86)` to just `Program` does not help.